# How to get all table names except pivot tables from the mysql database in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table

I am trying to get all the tables except pivot tables from the mysql database in laravel 5, is there any solution to get?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you know which tables are pivot and which are not?

Comment: Exactly, but the requirement is this need to get table names except pivot tables.